# Speeding up zotero-overleaf sync

Tags: overleaf, zotero

I use the integration of zotero and overleaf to store the references I use. However, now that the bibliography file is very big, it takes a long time to add every single reference to the .bib file.

Is there a way to speed this up? Perhaps a way in which only some files are uploaded?

Comment: Have you contacted the Overleaf Helpdesk with your query? Their LaTeX support staff is top notch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a member of Overleaf's support team. Please feel free to reach out to Overleaf support directly for Overleaf-specific questions: https://www.overleaf.com/contact

Very large Zotero libraries can be slow in Overleaf (slow for autocompleting citations, slow for advanced reference search, and slow for compiling).

The recommendation would be to put the references that you are using for the specific project in a Zotero group. Zotero provides an API that allows you to access a specific group as an addressable resource (URL). You can either use the URL directly to bring the .bib file into Overleaf, or use Overleaf's Zotero integration, which does support groups. Please see: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_to_link_your_Overleaf_account_to_Mendeley_and_Zotero#Using_Zotero.